# How to escape text coming from PHP in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, string-literals, html-escape-characters

I am using jPlayer to display some videos and I create the playlist on the fly in a php foreach statement:

```
var playlistacting = 
            [
        <?php foreach($this->result as $val){?>
                {
                    title:  '<?php echo $val->getTitle();?>',
                    artist: '<?php echo $val->getDes();?>',
                    poster: "<?php echo $val->getVideoId();?>.jpg",
                    thumb:  "<?php echo $val->getVideoId();?>.jpg",
                    flv:    "<?php echo $val->getVideoId();?>.flv",
                },
        <?php }?>
];
```

and `$val->getDes()` example would be `I have a one-hour (approximately) solo musical revue called "Manhattan With A Twist". The entire...`

the error I get is

```
unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

artist: 'I have a one-hour (approximately)solo musical revue called "Manhattan W...

jquery.js (line 2, col 32)
```

and is poining to the `'` at the beginning of the string.

I can do this: `title:  "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($val->getTitle());?>",`

and I will get the same error but with `"` instead of `'`.

I'm not sure what is happening here. Is it complaining about that `'` not being escaped or what?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply use json_encode:

```
var playlistacting = <?php echo json_encode($this->result);?>;
```

Comment: i can see using it on a array, but why is working on this string

Comment: It's not working on a string, it's working on an array/object that contains strings.

Comment: I don't know why this worked. `json_encode()` is the right answer, but from what you've shown us of your `result` object, it won't produce all the right data just with a single call to json_encode(). I would expect you'd need to build a PHP array first from `$this->result` into the format you want, and `json_encode()` that.

Comment: @Spudley: that's correct, the file-extensions are missing. But they seem to be static, so they also may be appended in javascript later when they are needed.

Comment: @Spudley it works perfect, the text comes back with all quotes and everything.

Comment: well, ill not use json encode on the links,they don't cause problems because pf the way they are stored

Comment: @Patrioticcow - yes, it will encode the object correctly; you'll get a perfect javascript representation of all the object properties; what I meant was your original code is building specific named elements, and adding hard-coded strings to the values; those values won't come out like that if you simply json_encode the whole object; if you want your finished javascript to look the way you wrote it in the question, you'll need to build a PHP array that matches what you want, and json_encode that.